# openpyxl: Iterate through all the rows and get the row data in a tuple

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

How do I iterate through all the rows in an xls sheet, and get each row data in a tuple. So at the end of the iteration, I should have a list of tuples with each element in the list, being a tuple of row data.
For instance: This is the content of my spreadsheet:

`testcase_ID         input_request        request_change
 test_1A             test/request_1       YES
 test_2A             test/request_2       NO
 test_3A             test/request_3       YES
 test_4A             test/request_4       YES`

my final list should be:
[(test_1A, test/request_1, YES), 
 (test_2A, test/request_2, NO), 
 (test_3A, test/request_3, YES), 
 (test_4A, test/request_4, YES)]

How can I do this in openpyxl?

Comment: It looks like you have not even consulted the documents for the library,

Answer (score -1):

I think this task would be easier with `xlrd`. However, if you want to use `openpyxl`, then assuming that  `testcase_ID` is in column `A`, `input_request` in column `B`, and `request_change` in column `C` somehting like this might be what you are looking for:

```
import openpyxl as xl

#Opening xl file
wb = xl.load_workbook('PATH/TO/FILE.xlsx')
#Select your sheet (for this example I chose active sheet)
ws = wb.active

#Start row, where data begins
row = 2
testcase = '' #this is just so that you can enter while - loop

#Initialiazing list
final_list = []

#With each iteration we get the value of testcase, if the cell is empty
#tescase will be None, when that happens the while loop will stop
while testcase is not None:

    #Getting cell value, from columns A, B and C
    #Iterating through rows 2, 3, 4 ... 
    testcase = ws['A' + str(row)].value
    in_request = ws['B' + str(row)].value
    req_change = ws['C' + str(row)].value

    #Making tuple
    row_tuple = (testcase, in_request, req_change)
    #Adding tuple to list
    final_list.append(row_tuple)

    #Going to next row
    row += 1

#This is what you return, you don't want the last element
#because it is tuple of None's
print(final_list[:-1])
```

If you want to do it with `xlrd` this is how I would do it:

```
import xlrd

#Opening xl file
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('PATH/TO/FILE.xlsx')
#Select your sheet (for this example I chose first sheet)
#you can also choose by name or something else
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

#Getting number of rows and columns
num_row = ws.nrows
num_col = ws.ncols

#Initializing list
final_list = []

#Iterating over number of rows
for i in range(1,num_row):
    #list of row values
    row_values = []
    #Iterating over number of cols
    for j in range(num_col):  
        row_values.append(ws.cell_value(i,j))

    #Making tuple with row values
    row_tuple = tuple(row_values)
    #Adding tuple to list
    final_list.append(row_tuple)


print(final_list)
```

Adding `xlrd` index specifications comments at the end for easy reading:

- Deleted if statement, when num_row is 1 then for-loop never happens
- xlrd indexes rows beginning at 0
- for row 2 we want index 1
- Columns are also zero-indexed (A=0, B=1, C=2...)

Comment: This is great! you mentioned about xlrd right? Could you give me the xlrd solution too? I dont mind using that if its simpler.

Comment: @Namratha as you can see you get the number of rows from the start if you use xlrd, which is neat, you will not have that extra element at the end with a tuple of `None`s. The only drawback is that manipulating cells is not as intuitive with `xlrd` as `openpyxl` I usually use them both depending on the situation at hand.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! But is there a way to grab the columns more dynamically, instead of hardcoding the values? I am talking about the lines "testcase = ws.cell_value(i,0)
        in_request = ws.cell_value(i,1)
        req_change = ws.cell_value(i,2)". If I add another column, I have to manually change the code right? Instead, can that be more automated? I guess i'll have to go with a nested for loop in that case right?

Comment: @Namratha, yes you'll have to go with a nested loop in that case, I edited the answer for a more generic case. If you like the answer feel free to upvote or accept it ;)

Comment: This is a poor and incorrect answer. `for row in ws` is sufficient.

Comment: Great! I think this is what I was looking for! Thanks much @Nerdrigo... Unfortunately my reputation is below 50, because of which I am not able to cast votes. :(